# Coredns unable to depoy

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I have installed a cluster but can't seem to configure coredns to run. I get the following message when I do a `kubectl describe replicaset -n kube-system:`

```
Error creating: pods "coredns-7945fb857d-" is forbidden: unable to validate against any pod security policy: [pod.metadata.annotations[seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod]: Forbidden:  is not an allowed seccomp profile. Valid values are runtime/default pod.metadata.annotations[container.apparmor.security.beta.kubernetes.io/coredns]: Forbidden: AppArmor profile must be set pod.metadata.annotations[container.seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/coredns]: Forbidden:  is not an allowed seccomp profile. Valid values are runtime/default spec.containers[0].securityContext.capabilities.add: Invalid value: "NET_BIND_SERVICE": capability may not be added
```

can anybody point me in the right direction

Comment: have you already deployed your pod network add-on?

Comment: Yes, Calico and the pod for that get created 
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-59f54d6bbc-8wv5t   1/1     Running   0          5h51m

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the coreDNS pod wasn't even created due to a [Pod Security Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#enabling-pod-security-policies):

> PodSecurityPolicies are enforced (...) but doing so without authorizing any policies will prevent any pods from being created in the cluster.

In this specific case, is complaining that the profile in the Seccomp annotation is not valid:

> [seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod]: Forbidden:  is not an allowed seccomp profile.

You can check [here a list of valid profiles](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#seccomp) and an [example of a custom one](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.4/docs/design/seccomp.md#custom-profile).